# Eclipse auto-generates wrong type of JavaDoc template for getters and setters

Tags: java, eclipse

I have configured a customized template for getter and setter JavaDocs in Eclipse's code templates. However, it's only used when I use the "generate getters and setters" dialog (which creates the methods.

The template is not used when creating JavaDoc comments for existing getters and setters, either by simply typing `/**LF` or by right clicking the method and choosing Source > Generate Element Comment. When I do that, Eclipse seems to be using the generic method template, not the specific getter or setter template.

Is there any way to change this? If it matters, I'm using OS X 10.9.2 with Eclipse Kepler Service Release 2 (build ID 20140224-0627).

Answer (score 0):

Under preferences => Java => Code Style => Code Templates, there's a `Getter Body` and a `Setter Body`, which can be edited, by clicking `Edit` on the upper right of the fields outline view. Hope that helps...

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding you, I don't think that this answers the question. The getter and setter bodies match the bodies of getters and setters that I want to generate JavaDocs for. The getters and setters already exist. I want to generate JavaDocs for these existing methods. Eclipse simply doesn't recognize getters and setters when creating the JavaDoc comments.

Comment: Mike, I'm not the only one who was confused by your question, however, you can add javadoc comments as code. They'll appear as part of the method.

Comment: But if you insert the JavaDoc into the code template, won't that only be used when generating getters and setters? How can that be used to generate the JavaDoc for existing getters and setters?

Comment: Did you try it? Or are you just speculating?

Comment: I'm not sure what I'm trying here. Getter body modifies the body of getters. But I don't want to modify the body. The body is currently exactly how I want it to be. I want to add a JavaDoc comment to existing getters, but the generic method JavaDoc template is being used and not the getter JavaDoc comment template.